# HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name returns DefaultAppPool, why?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, iis

I'm trying to get the current user's Windows login but it just returns DefaultAppPool (the pool running the website). If I try and add impersonate in the web.config, I get the Windows user that runs IIS.

IIS configuration has Windows authentication enabled and anonymous authentication disabled.

**How do I get the user, that's visiting the website, instead?**

Comment: Okay probably I'm mistaken but I was pretty sure that User.Identity.Name will do the trick. I delete my answer, hope someone help you !

Comment: You shouldn't have - the answer wasn't the answer to my problem but it was correct nonetheless. Essentially, some extra Windows IDs were stored in the Credential Manager making our PC look like the server's user was logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that extra Windows IDs were stored in the Credential Manager making our PC look like the server's user was logged in.

My original code worked, it just didn't seem like it had been.

Answer (score 1):

```
string userName1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
string userName2 = User.Identity.Name;// don't take it from HttpContext
```

Check which one of this you need. Second one is property of the page !

Comment: Both return the Windows user running IIS.

Comment: do you take it second one from the Page.User.Identity.Name ?

Comment: Hmm, I'll double-check.

Comment: Add in the bit about checking the Credential Manager to delete any extraneous credentials and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'm not aware in depth of the problem probably it will be good to explain it seperate answer and mark your as correct in this case.